# Salesforce Report on OpportunityLineItem

Tags: reporting

I am looking for a way to create a report on OpportunityLineItem as Primary object.
But I couldnt see the opportunitylineitem in the list of primary objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't report on OpportunityLineItem as a "primary" object. It is a secondary object, and therefore can only be run as an Opportunity and Products report. If you want to report on opportunities that only have products, use the filter "Has Products equals True."

Comment: My scenario is to show all opportunitylineitems based on a checkbox to true and group by Opportunity.

Comment: Can i achieve this by standard salesforce report?

Comment: @AnuragA This should certainly be possible in the standard Opportunities and Products report.